# "mismatched input 'Date' expecting Identifier near '(' in column specification"

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

`ALTER TABLE test1 ADD PARTITION (Date='2013-11-20');`

Results in the following error:

`FAILED: Parse Error: line 1:84 mismatched input 'Date' expecting Identifier near '(' in column specification`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Date is a reserved word in HiveQL, as explained [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1868).

I changed the column name to `d` and it worked fine (which is quite unfortunate, because the name `Date` is much more meaningful than `d`).